# Automatically adding timestamp to each column

Tags: excel, vba

so i have a sheet and whenever something in the range of A10:A23 is changed/updated, it is supposed to put a timestamp in the according column in Row B, however it isnt working and i have no idea why.

I already set the sheets code to "Worksheet" and "change"

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = A And Target.Column >= 10 And Target.Column <= 23 Then
        Cells(Target.Column, B) = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be confusing rows for Columns. `Target.Row` will never equal `A`. Also, rows and columns are indexed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will only change **one** cell at a time (which is not always true):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A10:A23")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

            Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now()

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```